# LDAP: error code 50 - cannot be added due to insufficient access rights

Tags: java, ldap, opends

I am trying to add account to OpenDS running of windows. 
When I tried to add the user, I get the following errors. I am new to OpenDS.
 Any tips apprecitated

```
org.springframework.ldap.UncategorizedLdapException: Operation failed; 
nested exception is javax.naming.NoPermissionException: [LDAP: error code 50 - The entry uid=test@example.com,ou=People,o=Drive,dc=company,dc=com cannot be added due to insufficient access rights];  
remaining name 'uid=test@example.com, ou=People, o=Drive'
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: check your privilege in openDS.

Comment: You must `bind()` before you modify. You have to [help us help you](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As it stands, your question will be put on hold as being *too broad*.

Answer (score -1):

You have insufficient permissions on the account you are using to perform the modify event.